# OpenERP 7 Deleted Modules Still Showing Installable

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

OpenERP 7 Deleted Modules Still Showing Installable. I was testing 3 modules in openerp 7. Once i uninstall those 3 module & delete from addons folder. Then update "Update Modules List". If i search those installer, then I found them to installable. How i can remove those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove module from list you have to delete module from modules list

[image]